# Composer and php errors when migrating code from osx to debian

Tags: php, macos, symfony, debian, influxdb

I have one problem after migrating Symfony 3 project from macbook OSX on Debian. The error is lunched by Symfony component ContextErrorExcetion. This is my terminal printscreen:

[image]

Comment: What version of php do u have on osx and debian? Perhabs, on osx u have php7 or above and on debian u have php lower than 7. Type decloration as string availible only on php7 or above http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration

Comment: Yes on my mac I have php 7 and on debian i have 5. Tnx